# Display a UIView / UIControl overlapping UIToolbar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, uitoolbar

I'm trying to display a large button at the bottom of the screen, so that it appears above the toolbar.

**Button Overlapping Toolbar**
[image]

My first attempt at this works on the iPad, and on the iPhone in Landscape mode, but the button appears behind the toolbar in Portrait mode. So, this is probably related to the difference in rendering with the Split View Controller:

```
addButton.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:48, height:48)
addButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"Button - Add"), for: .normal)

let topView = self.navigationController?.view
topView?.addSubview(addButton)
```

I don't want it to appear above all other view controllers, e.g. popovers and modal segues, so I can't place the button on the application's topmost window, i.e. the following doesn't give me the right result either:

```
let topView = UIApplication.shared.windows.first
topView?.addSubview(addButton)
```

The only solution that works for me is to add the button to the toolbar, but this isn't great because the touch zone for the button is clipped by the toolbar:

```
self.navigationController?.toolbar.addSubview(addButton)
let topView: UIView? = addButton.superview
```

So, does anyone know of a way to place a UIView or UIControl in a layer or view above the toolbar, but still on the active viewController?

Comment: if behind means that it's covered by it, try reordering the two clashing items on storyboard. The order in which they are listed there decides the priority on which item shows "in front" of the other.

Comment: You can't put a button on top of a toolbar using the storyboard, as far as I can tell.

Comment: So you don't want them overlapping? Why not use constraints then?

Comment: Maybe you can adjust the button layer position like `button.layer.zPosition = navigationController?.toolbar.layer.zPosition + 1`

Comment: Thanks Sergey - that did exactly what I wanted. If you add it as a formal answer, I will mark it as answered.